# docker-compose mysql container denies access to wordpress container

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with mysql 5.7 container denying access to wordpress container. I'm using docker-compose and I'm running docker on Mac OSX. Docker should be on latest version available.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: blog
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: blog_admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: userpasswd
    networks:
      - wordpress_net
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpasswd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blog
      MYSQL_USER: blog_admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userpasswd
    networks:
      - wordpress_net
networks:
  wordpress_net:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Logs from db container are:

```
2017-05-12T23:28:06.138429Z 321 [Note] Access denied for user 'blog_admin'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

Logs from wordpress container are:

```
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'blog_admin'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'blog_admin'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES) in - on line 22
```

docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
1b02f0146fe7        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint..."   25 minutes ago      Up 26 seconds       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   wordpress
5d932ed6c269        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint..."   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                       db
```

What have I tried:

1. Restarting docker host.
2. docker-compose rm -v and then docker-compose up -d again.
3. Logging in with those user credentials and root credentials outside of wordpress container.
4. Removing docker images and pulling them again from scratch.
5. Using root credentials in  `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST, WORDPRESS_DB_USER`

I can see all the env vars for db when I connect to db container. Wordpress container keeps restarting it self. I saw one answer on stack overflow which recommended flushing privileges and setting new user account but I want to know if I'm doing something wrong that could cause this problem to appear again on other machine.

Comment: could you use phpmyadmin to check if the "Host" of your root_user is set to "%"? also in your docker-compose try using "- links: - db" in your wordpress-service

Comment: @ad_on_is Hi my problem is fixed now. Yeah I've tried to add phpmyadmin to docker-compose.yml but it was not working as I couldn't connect to mysql even as root. It was denying access even when I left root password blank. So not even phpmyadmin could connect to it. Nevertheless I fixed it by approach described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What have I done:

`docker-compose rm -v` hasn't worked for me as I've always used `docker-compose down` to shutdown containers. And I think this is the root of the problem.

- I deleted the folder with my `docker-compose.yml` and created a new one.
- Then I created a compose file with just the config for `mysql` container, launched it and tried to connect to the `mysql` server as `root`.
- It worked. Then I had to stop the container with `docker stop containerID`.
- Then I ran `docker-compose rm -v`(For some reason `rm -v` works only when you stop the container. Not when you use `docker-compose down` this caused the db's state to persist, as I used a volume for the db container) and completed the yml file with the wordpress container config.

**I've ended up with something like this:**

```
version: '2'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress-blog
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

**NOTE:** I had a problem previously not only connecting to the database from the wordpress container, but also from the db container itself. The method I described above helped me to solve this issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem. My solution was to change the name of the volume in the docker-compose.yaml file, then run: docker-compose up -d --build' Then, while the container was running, I used: 'docker system prune --volumes' to get rid of the old, obsolete volume.

Answer (score 6):

**Change:**

```
WORDPRESS_DB_USER: blog_admin
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: userpasswd
```

**To:**

```
WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: rootpasswd
```

**And then:**

`docker-compose up -d --build`

Your username `Blog_admin` doesn't have access to `create database`.

Comment: I've done that but result seems to be same. I'm getting same error logs just this time for root

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution
change

```
volumes:
- db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

to something like

```
volumes:
- db_data:/var/lib/mysqlx
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: Thanks its work for me, although i did not know what the effect of this modif